# Does drush have built-in variables or macros?

Tags: drush

Does `drush` have built-in or predefined variables or macros?

An example would be like the base directory of the Drupal installation, database name, passwords etc? Something like the values displayed in `drush status`

Comment: Doesn't `variables` exist as a permissible tag? It is forcefully converted to `persistent-variables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you source the file examples/example.bashrc from your ~/.bashrc file, then you can do useful things like `cd %root` or `cd @site:%root`.  Without sourcing that file, you can use `cd $(drush dd %root)`.  If you want to go to a module or theme directory, `cd $(drush dd %devel)` also works.  Using the %path aliases without qualifying them with a @site alias does, of course, require that your cwd be inside some Drupal site (or $options['root'] must be set in some drushrc.php file).

Comment: I take it that the '@', '%' are bash symbols, that drush doesn't have its own special syntax or prefixes that are separate from shell/bash prefixes which refer to settings in drushrc or some other drush related values that can be computed from the Drupal environment and the current directory?
(a bit of a mouthful, I hope you get the drift :))

Comment: No, $ is used for Bash variables.  @ and % are interpreted by Drush.  %root is calculated based on the cwd.